# I have a contact form that on the css styles that fit mobile devices it won't let me input data

Tags: php, html, css, forms

So I can fill out the form on the desktop size but when I got to fill it out on mobile sizes (640, 480, and 320) it doesn't let me.  I found out something by trying things and just happen to have my cursor outside my `contactform` div that has the form inside it. Then it let me type in everything but the message box unless I use tab and am still outside the div. I find it odd?

[benlevywebdesign.com](http://benlevywebdesign.com/) 
The bottom of the page is where the form is for you to test out the mobile layouts for 640, 480, and 320.

Here is the contact form

```
<form id="form1" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">    

        <fieldset>
            <p class="form">
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="30" />
            </p>
            <p class="form">
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" size="30" />
            </p>
            <p class="form">
                <label for="web">Website</label>
                <input type="text" name="web" id="web" size="30" />
            </p>            
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>                                                                          
            <p class="form">
                <label for="message">Message</label>
                <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
            </p>                                
        </fieldset>                 

        <p class="submit"><button name="submit" type="submit">Send</button></p>

    </form>
```

Here is my css style for 480 and 320

```
@media screen and (max-width:480px){

@media screen and (max-width:320px){


#form1{
    padding-top:5px;
    }

#form1 fieldset{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:none;    
    float:left;
    display:inline;
    width:190px;
    margin-left:15px;
    }

#form1 legend{display:none;}    
#form1 p{margin:.5em 0;}    
#form1 label{display:block;}    
#form1 input, #form1 textarea{      
    width:175px;
    border:1px solid #B7B7B7;
    background:#fff;
    padding:3px;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left 25, from(#FFFFFF), color-stop(4%, #EEEEEE), to(#FFFFFF));
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF, #EEEEEE 1px, #FFFFFF 25px);
    }   

#form1 textarea{
    height:120px;
    width:175px;
    overflow:auto;
    }   

#form1 p.submit{
    clear:both;
    padding:0 25px 5px 25px;
    margin:0;
    text-align:right;
    }   

#form1 button{
    font-family:Trebuchet MS;
    font-size:14px;
    width:105px;
    height:35px;        
    border:none;
    background-color:#484749;
    color:#fff;
    border-radius:4px;
    cursor:pointer;
    text-align:center;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried resizing your browser and viewing your site on a PC (I'm using FF), it goes all kinds of screwy. Also Firebug says you have 15 errors and 10 warnings - might be worth trying to fix these first before going back to mobile devices.

Heres a short video of the issues: http://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/clhwo4GGI

Comment: Yes I know it does that bu do you have google chrome or internet explorer because it doesn't do those crazy things on any other browser and those errors are tiny little no big deal things.

Comment: It doesn't do those things on Chrome, Safari, or on my mobile devices so I don't know why it is doing that. But what about my original issue of having to have the cursor outside the `contactform` div because I can't control the curson on mobile devices

Comment: I've added a video to show the issues and why it might be causing other issues with overlapping etc...

Comment: If you look at my website on desktop layout and you put your mouse over any box besides my bio(the top one) you will notice a little box shadow on hover. On my mobile styles I had that turned off with `display:none` and my forms didn't work but when I commented `display:none` out of the css my contact forms work. But I don't want the hovers to display on mobile because you don't really have hovers